# $\lambda$ for which {$\sin x \cos y = 2\lambda - 4, \sin y \cos x = 1- \lambda$} have solutions

Tags: trigonometry

**My attempt:**

I tried to find the values of $\sin (x+y)$ and $\sin (x-y)$, but am unsure if this is the right approach and what conditions are to be fulfilled for the given system of equations to have solutions.

Given $$\sin x \cos y = 2\lambda - 4 \implies$$ $$2\sin x \cos y = 4\lambda-8 \implies$$ $$\sin(x+y) +\sin(x-y) =4\lambda - 8 \tag{1}$$

and

$$\sin y \cos x = 1-\lambda \implies$$ $$2\sin y \cos x = 2 - 2 \lambda\implies$$ $$\sin(x+y) +\sin(y-x) = - 2\lambda + 2\tag{2}$$

$\sin (y-x) = - \sin(x-y)$ and from $(1)$ and $(2)$

$$\sin(x+y) = \lambda - 3$$ $$\sin (x-y) =3\lambda - 5$$

What to do next (if I am on the right track)? Hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. The original equations have a solution iff the equations
$$\sin(x+y) = \lambda - 3$$ $$\sin (x-y) =3\lambda - 5$$
have  a solution. Now given any $t,s \in \mathbb  R$ we can always find $x,y$ such that $x+y=t$ and $x-y=s$. Hence we only have to find $\lambda $ such that
$$\sin t = \lambda - 3$$ $$\sin s =3\lambda - 5$$
have a solution. The conditions are $-1\leq \lambda -3 \leq 1$ and $-1 \leq 3\lambda -5 \leq 1$.

The only possibility is $\lambda =2$.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote,

$\sin(x+y) +\sin(x-y) =4\lambda - 8 \tag{1}$

$\sin(x+y) - \sin(x-y) = - 2\lambda + 2\tag{2}$

Now with $(1) + 2 \times (2)$

$3 \sin (x+y) - \sin (x-y) = -4$

What does it mean for values of $\sin (x+y)$ and $\sin (x-y)$ given value of $\sin$ function is in $(-1, 1)$?

That should lead you to the value of $\lambda$.